# Why does my command always say "undefined"?

Tags: discord, discord.js, deepl

I have a problem with the DeepL API which means that when I use the command, it doesn't give me the translated text but always the word "undefined".

I'll leave you my code, if you can help me please!

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const deeplApiKey = "";
const config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'traduction',
    description: 'Permet de traduire le texte en anglais',
    dm: false,
    permission: 'Aucune',
    category: "Utilitaires",
    options: [
        {
            type: "string", 
            name: "text",
            description: "Texte à traduire",
            required: true,
        },
    ],
      
    async run(bot, interaction, args) {

        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    'auth_key': deeplApiKey,
                    'text': interaction.content,
                    'target_lang': 'EN'
                })
            });
    
            const data = await response.json();
            const translatedText = data.translations[0].text;
            interaction.editReply({ content: translatedText, ephemeral: true })
    
        } catch (error) {
            interaction.editReply({ content: 'La traduction à échoué', ephemeral: true })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `data.translations[0].text` is undefined. Have you tried `console.log(data)` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is not the string but something like `null` in other languages - there is no `text` attribute on that object.
There is an error in your request - the API key has to be passed as a header, as documented in the [API docs](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/api-access/authentication).

```
const response = await fetch('https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': `DeepL-Auth-Key {deeplApiKey}`
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    'text': [interaction.content],
                    'target_lang': 'EN'
                })
            });
```

More generally, DeepL offers a [Node library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-node) to interact with their API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I no longer have any errors but it keeps telling me "the translation has failed".

Comment: Sorry can you please provide me with
1. The command you use to run your code
2. The exact error message you get (just copy paste it)
3. Your updated code?

Comment: I just saw in your code, does this branch get executed now? 
`catch (error) {interaction.editReply({ content: 'La traduction à échoué', ephemeral: true })}`
Can you please log the HTTP error you get?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw an error in my code - `text` is an array of strings, not a string. So you've to wrap your string in an array. I updated my code

Comment: I've copied your code but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. I'm assuming there's a problem retrieving the text to be translated (or else the problem comes from the deepl api, which I doubt very much), which means that the bot only replies "the translation failed". I've copied your code but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. I'm assuming there's a problem getting the text to be translated (or else the problem comes from the deepl api, which I doubt very much), which means that the bot only replies "the translation failed".

Comment: `interaction.editReply({ content: 'La traduction à échoué', ephemeral: true })` in this line, please also log the `error` object that you get, and ideally also the `interaction.content` to make sure it is correct.

One way to do that would be

`interaction.editReply({ content: 'Error when translating message "' + interaction.content + '", the following error occured: '+ error.toString(), ephemeral: true })`

Comment: It replied ```"Error when translating message "undefined", the following error occured: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate reason: Unexpected end of JSON input"```.